# How to find numbers following specific punctuation

Tags: python, pandas, string

Text:

```
3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE  Comments 234:  FOUND NO EMPLOYEE  ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments:   | 10. ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS 7-38-030(C), NO CITATION ISSUED.  | 47. FOOD & NON-FOOD
```

Background: inputs are separated by `|`, the goal is to find the first number and all numbers after punctuation `|`

The preferred outcome is = [3,5,10,47]

**Notice**: avoiding 234,7-38-030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option -  (I think using `re` is **better**.. but anyway..)

```
data = '3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE  Comments 234:  FOUND NO EMPLOYEE  ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments:   | 10. ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS 7-38-030(C), NO CITATION ISSUED.  | 47. FOOD & NON-FOOD'


def _get_int(val:str):
  if not val[-1] == '.':
    return None
  try:
    x = int(val[:-1])
    return x
  except ValueError:
    return None

numbers = []
for x in data.split():
  z = _get_int(x)
  if z is not None:
    numbers.append(z)
print(numbers)
```

output

```
[3, 5, 10, 47]
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach missed number 3 and miss-included 234,7,-38,-30 into the result.

Outcome: `[' 234', '. | 5', ':   | 10', ' 7', '-38', '-030', '.  | 47']`

```
def multi_re_find(patterns,phrase):
    '''
    Takes in a list of regex patterns
    Prints a list of all matches
    '''
    for pattern in patterns:
        print ('Searching the phrase using the re check: %r' %pattern)
        print (re.findall(pattern,phrase))
        print ('\n')
```

```
test_patterns = [r'\W+''\d+']
multi_re_find(test_patterns,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with a lookahead:

```
s = '3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE  Comments 234:  FOUND NO EMPLOYEE  ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments:   | 10. ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS 7-38-030(C), NO CITATION ISSUED.  | 47. FOOD & NON-FOOD'

import re

re.findall('\d+(?=\.)', s)
```

Or to ensure matching the beginning of the line or after a `|`  you can also add a lookbehind:

```
re.findall('(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\| ))\d+(?=\.)', s)
```

Output:

```
['3', '5', '10', '47']
```

And to get a list of integers:

```
list(map(int, re.findall('\d+(?=\.)', s)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !! Could you explain a little bit more, which parameter stands for the |, and  how to read (?=\.) ？many thanks !!!

Comment: I just added an option for the `|`, see my edit. The `(?=\.)` checks that there is a dot after the number but does not include this in the match

Comment: Why not `(\d+)\.`?